# Q: Cannot install “mediapipe” library on anaconda

Tags: python, mediapipe

I am trying to install mediapipe using

`pip install mediapipe`

but I am getting this error.

`ERROR: could not find a version that satisfies the requierement mediapipe. no matching distribution found for mediapipe.`

Answer (score 0):

Mediapipe supports does not support all python versions. Please visit https://pypi.org/project/mediapipe/#files and see if there is a version matching yours, download it, cd (change directory) of the console to the folder where you downloaded the file, and run

```sh
pip install filename.whl
```